# Надо спарсить с сайта вопросы и ответы на них, но чтобы до них добраться надо перейти в обсуждения данного вопроса, как реализовать?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Надо спарсить с сайта вопросы и ответы на них, но чтобы до них добраться надо перейти в обсуждения данного вопроса, как реализовать?
Вот сам сайт с нужным разделом: https://www.avvo.com/topics/landlord-tenant-law/advice?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search_topic_advice_search%5Bstate%5D=CA&search_topic_advice_search%5Bquery%5D=security+deposit&search_topic_advice_search%5Bcontent_type%5D=Q%26A&commit=Search
Пытаюсь делать так:
1) Перехожу по урлу
2) Захожу в 1-й пост, собираю нужную инфу, выхожу
3) Пытаюсь зайти на некст (не выходит)
+ ко всему на втором этапе выбивает ошибку "selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of  is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed"
Сам код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException as TE
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = "https://www.avvo.com/topics/landlord-tenant-law/advice?order=recency&page=1&search_topic_advice_search[content_type]=Q%26A&search_topic_advice_search[query]=security+deposit&search_topic_advice_search[state]=CA"

def get_url(driver, url):
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)


def page_pagination(driver):
    divs_pagination = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-12 advice-content']/div[@class='js-documents-list gtm-context']/div[@class='v-topic-page-card-list']/div[@class='card topic-advice-question-card']")
    for div_pagination in divs_pagination:
        div_pagination.click()
        time.sleep(2)


def get_content(driver):
    # divs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-12 advice-content']/div[@class='js-documents-list gtm-context']/div[@class='v-topic-page-card-list']/div[@class='card topic-advice-question-card']")
    # for div in divs:
    # div = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='card topic-advice-question-card']/div[@class='row']/div[@class='col-xs-12 u-margin-top-half']/a[@class='block-link']").click()
    # time.sleep(3)
    try:
        span = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-12']/div[@id='qa-body-display']/p[@class='a button btn btn-link u-vertical-padding-0']/span[@class='icon-chevron-down-after-blue']").click()
        time.sleep(2)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        mores_lawyer = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-12 gtm-context']/div[@id='answers_container']/div[@class='card qa-lawyer-card qa-answer v-borderless']/div[@itemscope='itemscope']/div[@id='answer-9088247']/div[@class='row answer-body']/div[@class='col-xs-12']/button[@class='btn btn-link u-vertical-padding-0']")
        for more_lawyer in mores_lawyer:
            more_lawyer.click()
            time.sleep(2)
    except:
        pass

    date_question_post = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-12 gtm-context']/div[@id='answers_container']/div[@class='card qa-lawyer-card qa-answer v-borderless']/div[@itemscope='itemscope']/div[@id='answer-9088247']/div[@class='row answer-metadata']/div[@class='col-xs-12']/ul[@class='inline-list']/li[@class='text-muted small hidden-xs']")
    question_short = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[@itemprop='name']")
    question_long = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@itemprop='text']")
    name_lawyer = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@itemprop='name']")
    lawyer_answer = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-12 gtm-context']/div[@id='answers_container']/div[@class='card qa-lawyer-card qa-answer v-borderless']/div[@itemscope='itemscope']/div[@id='answer-9088247']/div[@class='row answer-body']/div[@class='col-xs-12']/div[@id='answer-body-9088247']")

    name_data_question_post = date_question_post.text
    name_short = question_short.text
    name_long = question_long.text
    name_of_lawyer = name_lawyer.text
    name_of_lawyer_answer = lawyer_answer.text
    print(name_short, "\n" ,name_long, "\n" ,name_data_question_post ,"\nLawyer name: ", name_of_lawyer, "\nLawyer answer:", name_of_lawyer_answer)
    return (name_short, name_long, name_of_lawyer, name_data_question_post, name_of_lawyer_answer)



get_url(driver, url)
urls = page_pagination(driver)
for url in urls:
    get_content(driver)
    get_url(driver, url)


driver.close()
```

Больше идей, как реализовать нету

Comment: Для парсинга данных в вашем случае больше подойдет beautifulsoup. Советую ознакомиться с этой библиотекой, там вы найдете решение

Answer (score 0):

StaleElementReferenceException вы получаете, потому что сначала получайте ref на элемент, кликаете на первого, у вас меняется DOM, и потом хотите снова кликать на второй, но уже элемент потерян. Вы на другой странице

Нужно делать следующее.

найти и запомнить размер элементов

```
divs_pagination = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-12 advice-content']/div[@class='js-documents-list gtm-context']/div[@class='v-topic-page-card-list']/div[@class='card topic-advice-question-card']")

count=len(divs_pagination)
```

потом, вы кликаете на первый элемент

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div<пропуск>-question-card'][1]").click()
```

собираете информацию, кликаете назад, потом кликаете на творой

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div<пропуск>-question-card'][2]").click()
```

собираете снова информацию и кликаете назад.

но можно сделать по-другому.

1. открываете страницу
2. получаете все элементы "//div<пропуск>-question-card']"
3. с каждого элемента вытаскиваете значение аттрибута href
4. какая-нибудь фукция на вход получает href и возвращает нужные данные

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ответ, но вопрос я уже решил подругому.
Получил ссылки на посты, а затем банально переходил по ним.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException as TE
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time


def get_url(driver): # перехожу по урлу на нужный сайт
    driver.get('https://www.avvo.com/topics/landlord-tenant-law/advice?order=recency&page=1&search_topic_advice_search[content_type]=Q%26A&search_topic_advice_search[query]=security+deposit&search_topic_advice_search[state]=CA')
    time.sleep(3)


def get_content(driver): # собираю информация со страницы
    try:
        span = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-12']/div[@id='qa-body-display']/p[@class='a button btn btn-link u-vertical-padding-0']/span[@class='icon-chevron-down-after-blue']").click()
        time.sleep(2)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        mores_lawyer = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-12']/button[@class='btn btn-link u-vertical-padding-0']")
        for more_lawyer in mores_lawyer:
            more_lawyer.click()
            time.sleep(1)
    except:
        pass

    question_short = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[@itemprop='name']")
    question_long = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@itemprop='text']")
    date_question_posts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-12']/ul[@class='inline-list']/li[@class='text-muted small hidden-xs']")
    name_lawyers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@itemprop='name']")
    lawyer_answers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='row answer-body']/div[@class='col-xs-12']/div[@id='answer-body-9088247']")
    dates = []
    names = []
    answers = []
    for lawyer_answer in lawyer_answers:
        name_of_lawyer_answer = lawyer_answer.text
        answers.append(name_of_lawyer_answer)
    for date_question_post in date_question_posts:
        name_data_question_post = date_question_post.text
        dates.append(name_data_question_post)
    for name_lawyer in name_lawyers:
        name_of_lawyer = name_lawyer.text
        names.append(name_of_lawyer)

    name_short = question_short.text
    name_long = question_long.text

    print("\nQuestion: ",name_short, "\n" ,name_long, "\n")
    for date in dates:
        print(name_data_question_post)
    for name in names:
        print("\nLawyer name: ", name_of_lawyer)
    for answer in answers:
        print("\nLawyer answer: ", name_of_lawyer_answer)

    return (name_short, name_long, name_of_lawyer,name_of_lawyer_answer, name_data_question_post)


def page_pagination(driver):
    divs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-2']/a[@class='block-link']")
    urls = []
    for div in divs:
        url = div.get_attribute("href")
        urls.append(url)
    for url_1 in urls:
        trans = driver.get(url_1)
        time.sleep(2)
        get_content(driver)
        time.sleep(1)


def main():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    get_url(driver)
    page_pagination(driver)

    driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```